# RegistryCallback and RegCreateKeyEx

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, driver, windows-kernel

I want to monitor a windows machine. I created a windows service, and my idea is to be notified when a process tries to create a **new registry key.**

I use `RegistryCallback`  with the following signature

```
NTSTATUS RegistryCallback(
  _In_      PVOID CallbackContext,
  _In_opt_  PVOID Argument1,
  _In_opt_  PVOID Argument2
)
```

The RegistryCallback was registered with CmRegisterCallback . The problem is I am notified for every registry key creation , however I want to be notified only for creation of new registry keys , or at least getting the information  that this key was already exist, is there any way of doing so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't request specific notifications, you have to receive them all.  However, `Argument1` tells you what kind of operation is being performed so you can process only the ones you are interested in.  `Argument2` contains a pointer to various structures, depending on the value of `Argument1`, that give you more detailed information about the operations.  For example, when `Argument1` is `RegNtPostCreateKeyEx`, `Argument2` points to a [`REG_POST_OPERATION_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560971.aspx) struct whose `PreInformation` field points to a [`REG_CREATE_KEY_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560920.aspx) struct whose `Disposition` field tells you whether the key already existed or not.