# Can I use RegistryCallback in user mode application

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I need to monitor registry changes on windows machine. Is it possible to use RegistryCallback from a user mode windows service instead of from a windows driver? Most of the examples are used in a driver.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK no, because it is registered via [`CmRegisterCallback()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541918.aspx) and [`CmRegisterCallbackEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541921.aspx), which are only callable in kernel-mode drivers.

User-mode processes can use [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx), but it does not report detailed information about any changes made to the Registry.

[SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) uses a kernel-mode driver to monitor detailed Registry activity for display in a user-mode viewer.

Comment: But I need to know detailed information about any registry changes, is there any other way in user mode?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820641/registrycallback-and-regcreatekeyex

Comment: Not in user-mode, no.  You would have to scan the Registry manually and keep track of everything you are interested in, then re-scan it again every time a change gets notified, and determine the differences between the two scans.  At least in kernel-mode, the callback tells you what changed.  So, if you want to go this approach, you have to use a kernel-mode driver that relays information as needed to your user-mode app via an IPC mechanism.

Comment: http://forum.sysinternals.com/regmon-sourcecode_topic20980.html mentioned that "Process Monitor's registry filter uses SSDT hooks", does SSDT hooks also need to be done in kernel-mode driver?

Comment: [Hooking the System Service Dispatch Table (SSDT)](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/hooking-system-service-dispatch-table-ssdt/).  And Process Monitor uses SSDT hooks only on XP.

Comment: So SSDT also need to be hooked in a driver, correct?

Comment: According to the article I linked to, yes: "... the SSDT is located in a read-only memory ... Basically the WP is used to protect the read-only memory from being written to in kernel-mode, which allows additional protection when we’ve gained access to protected mode. Note that the WP bit only takes effect in kernel-mode, while **the user-mode code can never write to read-only pages**, regardless of the value stored in WP bit."  The SSDT is in read-only memory that only kernel-mode code can write to (after disabling the WP bit that protects it).

Comment: SysInternals Process Monitor uses a kernel-mode driver, but don't I need to install the driver? It seems that I only need to download the Procmon.exe and run it. I am wondering if I wrote a filter driver, do I also need to provide a driver installer?